# Cross-domain Jquery JSONP POST to Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jsonp

This is killing me. Trying to load data from a different domain from an API-sorts of that I'm trying to write. When sending JSON parameters as POST they get discarded, I've read somewhere that some special headers must be set before_filter:

```
  def cors_headers #set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'content-type, accept'
  end
```

Haven't had any luck with these though. Guess it's a browser limitation.

When I try sending the data as GET instead of POST, it gets added to the URL like this:

```
Completed in 959ms (View: 0, DB: 2) | 200 OK [http://www.somedomain.com/connector/browse/Sport.json?callback=jQuery16105855946165975183_1379526705493&{%22filters%22:[{%22filter%22:{%22attribute%22:%22id%22,%22op
erator%22:%22%3E%22,%22value%22:%222%22}},{%22filter%22:{%22attribute%22:%22id%22,%22operator%22:%22%3C%22,%22value%22:%227523%22}}]}&_=1379526723982]
```

So Rails basically can't see the filters which are the params that I'm trying to send

```
  Parameters: {"{\"filters\":"=>{}, "id"=>"Sport", "_"=>"1379526723982", "callback"=>"jQuery16105855946165975183_1379526705493"}
```

The jquery snippet I'm playing with is:

```
        $jq.ajax({url: "http://www.somedomain.com/connector/browse/" + x + ".json" + "?callback=?",
            type: "get", // tried post too
            dataType: "json", // tried jsonp too
            accepts: "json",
            data: req_data, // this is JSON.stringified already
            processData:false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8;",
            success: output
        });
```

The sample data I'm trying to send is this

```
{"filters":[{"filter":{"attribute":"id","operator":">","value":"2"}},{"filter":{"attribute":"id","operator":"<","value":"7523"}}]}
```

Has anyone an idea on how to sort this out?

Muchos gracias!

Comment: Later edit: the headers do get added to the response, 
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000, that's from CURL.

Comment: Later edit 2 - after reading around it seems a POST request should not work with JSONP, however looking at the log file, the JSON parameters do get posted and rails reads them just fine? It's just the output fails to reach the client (browser). Thinking maybe to store the output temporarily on the remote server side then do a 2nd GET call to fetch the output of the previous JSONP call. Thoughts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically the JS SOP  prevents us from sending a POST request and reading the response, but this can be worked around like this:

1) Compose the request data, send it as POST. Don’t expect to receive a response. Don’t use on success, use on complete instead. Add a random-ish variable to the request

2) Temporarily store the response on the server side in a file or session variable or memcached server, use the random var mentioned above as key within the store.

3) send a 2nd JSON AJAX call to fetch the cached object.

With memcached, make sure the cached responses get removed from time to time or expire, in my case the app gets a lot of traffic, it would spam my memcache servers with junk if not set to expire.

[here's some sample code](http://www.flinkwise.com/technology-blog/a-way-to-send-json-p-post-requests-to-another-domain-with-jquery-and-rails-in-the-back-end/)